# How can I find the right parameters to feed my Python function?

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I cant figure out how to provide the right parameter for my function that works with the Dropbox API.

```
def getSharedLink(full_path):
    try:
        link = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(full_path,True,PendingUploadMode.folder).url
    except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as err:
        return err
    return link
```

I get this error: AttributeError: 'Dropbox' object has no attribute 'PendingUploadMode'

The function works fine when I leave PendingUploadMode.folder out, but I really need this functionality.

Comment: did you try dir(dbx)?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran What would list of class/function/variable names of the package help with determining the **parameters** for  for one of those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it out:

```
x = dropbox.sharing.PendingUploadMode.folder

def getSharedLink(full_path):
    try:
        link = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(full_path,True,x).url
    except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as err:
        return err
    return link
```

Answer (score 0):

`PendingUploadMode` seems to be an attribute of the `Dropbox.Api.Sharing`, not `Dropbox`.

[Source](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/N_Dropbox_Api_Sharing.htm)